# Radon Nykodym derivative process

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and a random variable $Z$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}Z=1$. Define the R-N random process $$Z(t)=\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathcal{F(t)}]$$For $0\leq s\leq t \leq T$, $$\mathbb{E}[Z(t)|\mathcal{F(s)}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathcal{F(t)}]|\mathcal{F(s)}]=\mathbb{E}[Z|\mathcal{F(s)}]=Z(s).$$

Can someone explain how the second equality is possible in the above line? Thanks!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{F}(t)$? If $\mathcal{F}(s)\subset \mathcal{F}(t)$, then this follows from the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties) of conditional expectations

Comment: Yes it is a filtration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic property of conditional expectations: if $\mathcal G_1 \subset\mathcal G_2$ then $E(Z|\mathcal G_1)=E(E(Z|\mathcal G_2)|\mathcal G_1)$. You can prove it easily using definition of conditional expectation.